# React Routes not working with Module Federation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend, micro-frontend

So I'm using React v18, Router v6 and Module federation

[this is root app routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU4Bm.png)

[this is Payments app routes in .packages/payments/scr/app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shQpM.png)

the problem is that `Payments` page is rendered and working fine, but all routes inside `Payments` not working at all [this is what i get, no errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/divW1.png)

My guess is that routes inside `Payments` are just not initialized and I don't understand why.[All `bootstrap.jsx` files are made accordingly by React v18 docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9hB6.png)

Adding `BrowserRouter` inside `Payments` app is causing error

> You cannot render `<Router>` inside another `<Router>`

Maybe I don't see something, let me know if you need any additional setup details.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include actual text code snippets instead of links to images of your code. Images are less accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main `App` code is correct when it appends a wildcard `"*"` matcher to the routes for the descendent routes to be matched.

```
<Route
  path="/payments-kz/*"
  element={<PaymentsKzPage store={store} />}
/>
```

The issue is in the `PaymentsKzPage` rendering the descendent routes. The nested `Routes` component builds its routes *relative* to the parent route, e.g. `"/payments-kz"`. The descendent routes are incorrectly prepending a `"payments-kz"` path segment.

Example:

```
<Route
  path="/payments-kz/catalog/:categoryId/providers/:subcategoryId"
  element={<Providers />}
/>
```

The path actually resolves to:

`"/payments-kz/payments-kz/catalog/:categoryId/providers/:subcategoryId"`

To resolve the issue you should remove the `"/payments-kz"` segment from the descendent routes.

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/catalog/:categoryId/providers/:subcategoryId"
    element={<Providers />}
  />
  <Route path="/catalog/:id/:category" element={<Subcategories />} />
  <Route path="/catalog/:id" element={<Subcategories />} />
  <Route path="/providers/:subcategoryId" element={<Providers />} />
  .... etc ...
</Routes>
```

Comment: Wow. You just saved me. :-) I have been looking for a solution for this issue since quite a while. Thanks!